# A synonym for "completeness"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Sorry for being vague I can only remember that the word starts with a 'P'.
I've been trying to remember this word but I cannot recollect it.

Example:
"For the sake of p_____ I have added the example"

Comment: If the word *x* means "for the sake of completeness", wouldn't the sentence "for the sake of *x*" be redundant?

Comment: Yes @Joachim I have removed the redundant part now so my question is clearer, I was not entirely sure of its meaning at the time. Thanks!

Comment: Hello, Sai. Where have you looked for synonyms of 'completeness'? In a thesaurus?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're probably thinking of a collocation with a slightly different meaning, "for the sake of posterity". While *posterity* itself means future generations (or in practice, the people who come after you, like new employees at work), when you do something for posterity's sake, it's done extra thoroughly, making something self-contained, so that newcomers can make the most of it.

See some examples compiled by [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/posterity):

> - Each of the twenty-five contributors has felt the need to testify for the sake of posterity and as a human chronicle.
>   The Times Literary Supplement (2011)
> - For the sake of posterity, it's a good idea.
>   Times, Sunday Times (2008)
> - For posterity's sake, the high jinks and low humour were documented extensively on social media.
>   Times, Sunday Times (2016)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! This was on my mind all week, I can finally rest.

Answer (score 2):

A quick google search offers *plenitude*:

> the condition of being full or complete ([Oxford Languages](https://www.google.com/search?q=plenitude%20))

Comment: While this may be the word the OP has in mind, I'm not sure this word would be correct in the given example sentence (i.e., including an example in a text.)  It has more of a connotation of "containing the maximum possible amount" of something or of general abundance or plentifulness.